# Calling function from sheet module of another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to call a sub and a function that is inside a sheet module of another workbook, only the sub calling works. The function, even with the public scope, returns a void (zero lenght) string. Is it possible to fix that?

Code inside the sheet module of Sheet1 of Book1.xlsm:

```
Sub sMyMsg()
    MsgBox "hey sub"
End Sub

Public Function fMyMsg() As String
    fMyMsg = "hey func"
End Function
```

The code below is in a stardand module of another workbook (Book2.xlsm) that is in the same folder as Book1.slsm:

```
Sub Test_Sub() 'It works
    Application.Run "Book1.xlsm!Sheet1.sMyMsg"
End Sub

Sub Test_Func() 'It doesn't work. Gives me a void (zero lenght) string
    Dim s As String
    s = "test"
    s = Application.Run("Book1.xlsm!Sheet1.fMyMsg")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple to fix - don't put the code in a worksheet (or ThisWorkbook) module if you need to call it with `Run`. :) Note: it's actually not relevant to the problem that the calling code is in a different workbook. It wouldn't work like that from the same workbook.

Comment: Thanks, Rory! I use to put a lot of code into worksheet modules, so I had to ask and confirm that it is not possible. If you paste your comment as an answer, I will accept that. And, as you said, I will put the code in a standard module, not problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple to fix - don't put the code in a worksheet (or ThisWorkbook) module if you need to call it with `Run`. :)

Note: it's actually not relevant to the problem that the calling code is in a different workbook. It wouldn't work like that from the same workbook.